# Merging MP3 files in Linux Debian using PHP

Tags: php, linux, mp3, debian

What's the easiest way to merge the contents of several MP3 files into one using PHP 5.2 on Linux Debian system? I found some scripts that are supposed to do in PHP only, but they seem to be buggy. Perhaps there is a way to accomplish this task using command line programs, that I could install on my Linux Debian machine?

Comment: Do your file have the same bit rate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this: http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2009-September/022171.html

first you have to install sox. sudo apt-get install sox.

```
$ sox first.mp3 -r 44100 -c 2 -s -w first.raw
$ sox second.mp3 -r 44100 -c 2 -s -w second.raw
$ cat first.raw second.raw > concatenated.raw
$ sox -r 44100 -c 2 -s -w concatenated.raw concatenated.mp3
```

you can execute all these commands from php with exec().

Comment: Does this mean that it will change the bit rates to match?

Comment: by the way, one would need to use shell_exec() to get the output redirection to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Code taken from this link](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20040205164724481)

`cat first_part.mp3 second_part.mp3 third_part.mp3 > newfile.mp3`

They say that your file must have the same bit rate.

You can have bit rate using [mpg321](http://mpg321.sourceforge.net/)

`mpg321 -t first_part.mp3`

Hope it helps.

Comment: What about ID3 tags? MP3 files have headers and simply concatenating them would mess up the internal structure of the resulting file.

Comment: I only have one mp3 file to test it. I did cat my.mp3 my.mp3 my.mp3 > new.mp3 and the file is playable.

Comment: Is there a way that one can change the bit rate on the fly? If I have a large group of mp3s already, with varying bit rates.  What is the best thing to do?