# combining .mov movies with php

Tags: php, merge, quicktime, .mov

I have quicktime movies uploaded to my server that I need to combine together (there are sound tracks too). I cannot install ffmpeg (or anything else for that matter away from standard PEAR stuff).

I suppose an option open to me would be to open up the files with php. Can anyone provide any pointers on how to do this. Am I entering a world of pain?

Thanks in advance

Tudor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I entering a world of pain?

Probably yes. :)

I'm not familiar with the internal workings of the mov format, but if the format is not like MP3 (in which you can actually simply just [glue two files together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992311/merge-two-mp3-php/3992378#3992378) and they'll work in most players!), what you want to do is most likely not possible in pure PHP.

Comment: Most likely the best answer possible. I would advice getting on getting a VPS for these kind of things.

Comment: I've been putting off the VPS solution for sometime but I think you are right that now is the time to embrace it. More stuff to worry about! Thanks to both of you, Pekka and Stephen