# Merge two mp3 in php and update id3 meta duration

Tags: php, merge, mp3

I have found easy solution to merge two mp3 files :

```
file_put_contents('combined.mp3',
file_get_contents('file1.mp3') .
file_get_contents('file2.mp3'));
```

([Merge two mp3 php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992311/merge-two-mp3-php))

I have found a way to obtain real duration of created file :

(http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3)

But I can't arrive to update the new mp3 file with the real duration.

The generated file (combined.mp3) has the duration of the first file (file1.mp3) and not the duration of the sum of the 2 files.

Not a class or a function to update mp3 with his real duration ?

Merging mp3 in php is really impossible ?

I have found that :

[What is the best way to merge mp3 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files)

[Merging MP3 files in Linux Debian using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580807/merging-mp3-files-in-linux-debian-using-php)

I use shared hosting and mp3wrap is not a solution for me I think.

Comment: It's not possible to merge mp3s in PHP. You need an external tool to do that.

Comment: What tool ? Not existing a PHP script that use an external tool ?

Comment: You would still need an external tool which would merge the files. A possible tool is FFmpeg. But I'm sure there are other smaller tools available. In the end you either need to use `exec`, install a php module (to wrap the commands so you won't need access to shell commands) or an external web service which will do that job. Try googling.

Comment: Ok thanks. You know an external web service or API for that ?

Comment: Nope, hence the `try googling`.